# Can I get timeZone name by offset?

Tags: node.js, timezone, momentjs

I want to get the list of timeZoneIds (like: America/Los_Angeles) that at there, the time is 10am

So if UTC time is 1am, I will get all timezones of GMT +9 or offset = 10 * 60 * 60

How I can do it with moment.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
now = moment()
zones_at_10 = moment.tz.names().filter(zone => now.tz(zone).hour() == 10)
```

This will get all zones where the hour is currently 10 (including those where it is 10:01 as well as those where it is 10:31). If you wish to restrict to only the zones where it is currently 10:00, you can use this instead:

```
zones_at_10 = moment.tz.names().filter(zone => now.tz(zone).format("H:s") == "10:00")
```